# Jmeter: how to record https request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record HTTP S request but when accessing the URL, it is giving the certification error due to which i am not able to move forward. The request asks for windows credential but certification error occurs before the app prompts for authentication.
I tried to directly send the HTTPS request using the HTTP sampler and HTTP authorization manager for authentication but i am getting 'Unauthorized access', response code:401 in response. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resolved- In Jmeteer- on top side, theres SSL Manager. Just import your webserver (or your Site's ) SSL Certificate and save. While saving it will ask you for password- Enter the Certificate Files Password and save it.

Now you are ready to run a successful Test. I ahve tried this and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a JMeter proxy, if you use either Chrome or Firefox, any of these will offer you the choice to remember JMeter's certificate (not sure about IE). In most cases, that does the trick.

If you want to record a JMeter script without using a proxy, you should consider this option: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/231479-chrome-extension.
This browser extension allows you to record your traffic (HTTPs included) and generate a JMeter script without going through JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Recording and running the HTTPS application in JMeter is same as that of HTTP application. Just need to make sure that "use the same proxy server for all protocols" check box is selected or not in browser proxy setting. This check box should be selected to record the HTTPS application in JMeter.

Below are the steps:

IE = Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Proxy 
Server -> Advanced -> select check box "use the same proxy server for 
all protocols"

Fire Fox = Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings -> Manual Proxy 
Configurations (radio) -> select check box "use this proxy server for 
all protocols"

hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Can anyone tell me why i am getting unauthorized access in response when sending the request using HTTP sampler. I am using authorization manager to bypass windows authentication.

Comment: There is windows authorization then run Jmeter via command prompt, i have same type of Environment. just check 2.4.2 point from link http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#Can_JMeter_record_HTTPS_requests_using_the_recording_proxy.3F